# Reassigning all layers in gpkg and output as new one using PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, geopackage

I'm trying to reassign crs when writing snippets to do as described, combining with pre-existing Python code. I couldn't find the way to append to gpkg without saving the file onto local storage and then reading again.

What I'm describing here is something like:

```
import glob
import os

group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('nameOfTheGroup')
DIR = 'Users/name/Desktop/tmp/'

for child in group.children():
    lyr = child.layer()
    # I can only export the layer onto local
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
        lyr, DIR+lyr.name(), "utf-8", 
        QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326),  # Reassigning CRS here
        "ESRI Shapefile"
        )

os.chdir(DIR)
# reload from local
lyr_dir = glob.glob('*.shp')
lyrs = QgsVectorlayer(lyr, os.path.basename(), 'ogr')

# and save it to gpkg
params = {'LAYERS': lyrs,
          'OUTPUT': 'output.gpkg',
          'OVERWRITE': False,  # Important!
          'SAVE_STYLES': False,
          'SAVE_METADATA': False,
          'SELECTED_FEATURES_ONLY': False}

processing.run("native:package", params)
```

Well *technically* it does work, but it has so much redundant part!
I know it could go around with `ogr2ogr` with only 2 lines of code:

```
>>> ogr2ogr -f GPKG assignedCRS.gpkg -t_srs "EPSG:4326" input.gpkg
>>> ogrmerge.py -f GPKG -o output.gpkg assignedCRS.gpkg
```

**BUT** this has to be done in terminal.

How do I do this with PyQGIS only?

I might need to add extra functions other than assigning crs and to fully done without Python console has more readability and in one place.

Comment: I don't understand why you do this on the command line `ogrmerge.py -f GPKG -o output.gpkg assignedCRS.gpkg`. Is something missing from the command? As it stands now it only creates a new copy from assignedCRS.gpkg.

Comment: Yeah thats my mistake. I was doing this with *.shp. sorry bout that

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't something like this work, if all you need is a list of layers:

```
group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('nameOfTheGroup')
lyrs = []
for child in group.children():
    lyrs.append(child.layer())

# and save it to gpkg
params = {'LAYERS': lyrs,
          'OUTPUT': 'output.gpkg',
          'OVERWRITE': False,  # Important!
          'SAVE_STYLES': False,
          'SAVE_METADATA': False,
          'SELECTED_FEATURES_ONLY': False}

processing.run("native:package", params)
```

Comment: Apologize for rather late response, but your solution does not include the crs reproject part !

Comment: You can do that either when creating the list or when inserting the layers into the geopakage

Comment: Could you edit the answer to show hot it's done? This is the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316002/pyqgis-reproject-layer

Comment: Thank you! I'd try it out!